# Aggregate - na.omit and na.pass in R with factor (group by factor)?

Tags: r

I have a data set containing salaries test data. Not all cells have values hence I used na.action=na.pass,na.rm=TRUE but it gives me an error due to the fact that I want to aggregate with JobTitle which is factor?

So far I have developed below code:

```
aggregate(salaries$JobTitle, 
list(pay = salaries$TotalPay),
FUN=mean,
na.action=na.pass,
na.rm=TRUE)
```

My test data has the following columns:

```
'data.frame':   104 obs. of  36 variables:
 $ Id              : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ EmployeeName    : Factor w/ 11 levels "","ALBERT PARDINI",..: 10 7 2 4 11 6 3 5 9 8 ...
 $ JobTitle        : Factor w/ 9 levels "","ASSISTANT DEPUTY CHIEF II",..: 8 4 4 9 6 2 3 7 3 5 ...
 $ BasePay         : num  167411 155966 212739 77916 134402 ...
 $ OvertimePay     : num  0 245132 106088 56121 9737 ...
 $ OtherPay        : num  400184 137811 16453 198307 182235 ...
 $ Benefits        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ TotalPay        : num  567595 538909 335280 332344 326373 ...
 $ TotalPayBenefits: num  567595 538909 335280 332344 326373 ...
 $ Year            : int  2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 ...
 $ Notes           : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Agency          : Factor w/ 2 levels "","San Francisco": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ..
```

The error code which comes up is

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

etc...

I have tried with salaries$Id and it work like magic so I assume the code is correct and perhaps I need to change the data type for JobTitle?

Comment: Your `jobTitle` is a `factor `variable.  Which variable do you want to get the `mean` of?.  I think it should be the reverse. i.e. `aggregate(TotalPay~JobTitle, salaries, mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=na.pass)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are getting the `mean` of 'TotalPay`grouped by 'JobTitle', the`formula` method would be

```
aggregate(TotalPay~JobTitle, salaries, mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=na.pass)
```

Or use

```
aggregate(salaries$TotalPay, list(salaries$JobTitle), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
salaries <- data.frame(JobTitle = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20,
       replace=TRUE), TotalPay= sample(c(1:20, NA), 20))
```

Comment: Thank you. It work. I realized now that I have more records that can be displayed and the head function gives only 6 top records ordered by JobTitle. So, is there a function similar to SQL order by to sort by selected column and also, I suspect answer is not, but could we add Year to the aggregate? I am trying to have a year-on-year change in TotalPay for specific JobTitle. I am new to R hence all silly questions.

Comment: @Kalenji If you need "Year" also as grouping variable, you can add that also inside the `list` of 2nd way or use that in the formula method on the lhs of `~`.

Comment: @Kalenji Other options include `dplyr` or `data.table`. For example, `library(dplyr); salaries %>% group_by(JobTitle, Year) %>% summarise(Pay = mean(TotalPay, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: I have tried to use above code library(dplyr)
salaries <- group_by(JobTitle, Year) 
summarise(Pay = mean(TotalPay, na.rm=TRUE)) but it gives me an error. Error in summarise_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default. I have slightly modified the code to library(dplyr)
group_by(salaries, JobTitle, Year) 
summarise(salaries, Pay = mean(TotalPay, na.rm=TRUE)) but now it gives me average TotalPay (just one value).